# How to edit AndroidManifest.xml in PhoneGap 3

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest

It seems PhoneGap generates that file automatically when `config.xml` is modified.

I wish to add Ad network's activities, services, etc in `AndroidManifest.xml` but I can't find the correct way to edit that file.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Phonegap uses config.xml to create androidmanifest.xml when you add the android platform to a project.
It is also modified when you add plugins and build the project (for example, it adds the required permission for the plugin).

But you can also manually edit the file in `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` to add permissions, configure the activity or the application... it will not be lost when you rebuild your project.

Comment: It will be lost when running a new build, `cordova prepare` always override my custom manifest.xml

Comment: @Mirko did you find a solution?

Comment: @SebastienLorber it depends what you want to do, Cordova changes all the time and there are now options in config.xml to make some changes in AndroidManifest.xml that didn't exist at that time. Or you should be able to build a hook to update the file.

Comment: According to my tests (cordova 5.1.1) I was able to add some stuff to the manifest and running `cordova build android` did not erase the content, even with a modified `config.xml`. I need to add stuff like custom intent filters and activities so maybe it's a good idea to version control this manifest

Comment: @SebastienLorber I wanted to change `android:launchMode` in `AndroidManifest.xml` of my ionic project, I tried a hook, manual change etc but indeed running `cordova prepare` always resets it back to `singleTop`. How did you solve your issues?

Comment: @jakub.g `<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode"            value="singleTask"/> `

Answer (score 5):

Typically this is found in the "res" directory ( - src - gen [Generated Java Files] - Android - Android Dependencies - Referenced Libraries - assets - bin - libs - res - AndroidManifest.xml - proguard-project.txt - project.properties) of course this is depending on what version of Cordova you are using. Typically most of these things are specified in the config.xml for newer Phonegap builds from my understanding which is why you don't need to include an AndroidManifest.xml file when using Phonegap Build. I would recommend trying Configap to edit the main config.xml and see if any of the settings/services you need to access are options. [Configap can be found here!](http://configap.com/)

**forgot to mention I use Notepad++ to edit my .xml on the fly but you can also open in the sdk**

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to check out [cordova-custom-config](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-custom-config).

It supports many extra settings in the cordova `config.xml` to customise the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I'm using it to change the `android:configChanges` setting (adding `uiMode` to stop it from reloading when docking/undocking) and it works great.

The cordova-custom-config github page shows a full example with all supported options so it's very easy to setup.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays in Cordova, we can use [`<config-file>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file) and [`<edit-config>`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) in our `config.xml` to make simple custom changes to `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Examples copied from the docs:

```
<config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
    <activity android:name="com.foo.Foo" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</config-file>

<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/uses-sdk" mode="merge">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:maxSdkVersion="23" />
</edit-config>

<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']" mode="overwrite">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity" android:label="NewLabel" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
</edit-config>
```

Note: to use the `android:` namespace in your `config.xml`, you need to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to the root `<widget>` element.