# Can I write configuration from config.xml to AndroidManifest.xml in cordova applications

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, app-config

I want to add these lines to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
      <application  ... >
         .....       
         .....

      <service android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.MyService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.MyService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    </application>
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Is there a way to add these lines from the config.xml file ?

If yes how else what is the best way ?

Comment: Can you not modify the AndroidManifest.xml directly? Would that not be a more direct solution? Is there a specific reason you could not?

Comment: the  AndroidManifest.xml file is regenerated on every build  of the cordova project This is why I cannot write in it directly

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to edit AndroidManifest.xml in PhoneGap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518006/how-to-edit-androidmanifest-xml-in-phonegap-3)

Comment: My question is how to write the tags in the config.xml to get the result as I mentioned above in the question

Comment: I know that config.xml generates the  AndroidManifest.xml I tried to add the tags above as they are but it gives a build error

Comment: Is it `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` you are editing? [The documentation](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/) suggests that customisation is ok and will only get overridden on conflicts with your plugins' configuration/requirements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56026/discussion-between-meho0o0o0o0-and-indivisible).

Comment: hi @mehsen Do you find the solution to this? I need the same but I could not find the solution. As far as I read the more confuse I am. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

*PhoneGap Build aims to take away the pains of configuring SDKs and compiling native applications so you can focus on writing great code. As part of this, we obfuscate management of the platform configuration files – namely your Android Manifest and your iOS Property List. We configure these files based on the preferences you specify in your app’s config.xml file. However, the specifications of these xml files are constantly changing, and it would be impossible for us to expose all of the possible configurations through the use of simple preferences. So for those cases that we haven’t covered, we’re now enabling you to contribute xml directly to your Android Manifest and iOS Propertly List files, via the gap:config-file element (beta feature).*

Find out more on:
[Customize your Android manifest and iOS Property list on Phonegap build](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/)