# In Cordova 3.0 or greater android plugin. Where to list all the activities?

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to Cordova and android, If someone can tell me where to list all the activities in cordova android plugin. I know in android we do it android_manifest file but for cordova android plugin should i do it in plugin.xml? If yes, then what's the synatx? if no then where

Comment: A Cordova/PhoneGap app is still an Android app so it does have a manifest like a standard Eclipse/AS app.

Comment: I haven't seen any example in which plugin has an manifest file. Can you provide sample example?

Comment: I am creating project through CLI. Do I create android manifest manually and the add it to config file ?

Comment: It's been a long time since i last did PhoneGap development so my comment _is_ wrong. Check out http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/01/30/customizing-your-android-manifest-and-ios-property-list-on-phonegap-build/. I suggest taking the high ground with a standard app, embedding your html content in a webview if you need additional activities. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518006/how-to-edit-androidmanifest-xml-in-phonegap-3

Comment: You can open /platforms/android and you will find your android project. You could edit it to whatever you want, although it's not recommended to edit your platform code directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply .. I got the answer.. You have list all the activities in plugin.xml file under config-file tag. A sample plugin.xml would be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://www.phonegap.com/ns/plugins/1.0"
        id="com.example.hello"
        version="0.7.0">

  <name>Hello</name>

  <engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.4.0"/>
  </engines>

  <asset src="www/hello.js" target="js/hello.js"/>

  <js-module src="www/hello.js" name="hello">
    <clobbers target="hello" />
  </js-module>

  <platform name="android">

    <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
      <feature name="Hello">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.example.hello.Hello"/>
      </feature>
    </config-file>

    <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/*">
    <activity
            android:name="com.example.hello.Hello"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.hello.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
</config-file>
    <source-file src="src/android/Hello.java" target-dir="src/com/example/hello/"/>
    <source-file src="src/android/MainActivity.java" target-dir="src/com/example/hello/"/>
    <source-file src="platforms/android/src/libs/pass-v1.1.3.jar" target-dir="libs" />
    <source-file src="platforms/android/src/libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar" target-dir="libs" />
  </platform>
</plugin>
```