# config.xml vs AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, xml, cordova

In Cordova/Android, what's the difference between:

1. /appname/config.xml
2. /appname/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml

Which one do I edit, **or do I edit them both**?

I'm looking to do things such as:

1. force portrait mode (I found this setting in config.xml)
2. specify minimum sdk supported for android. (I found this setting in AndroidManifest.xml)

Comment: You have to edit the config.xml only, and if you need some changes on the AndroidManifest.xml that can't be done from the config.xml you can use a plugin that modifies the AndroidManifest.xml or a hook, but don't edit the AndroidManifest.xml manually, it might be overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Only update config.xml** (not AndroidManifest.xml as it gets generated whenever you do a build)

For example to do portait add in config.xml:

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
```

And to set minimum sdk add in config.xml:

```
<platform name="android">
      <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
</platform>
```

Comment: note however that I did have some edge cases that required adjusting the manifest file directly (because config.xml didn't support them). In that case, I just editted the manifest file directly and even though the build modified the manifest file it didn't throw away my edits.

Answer (score 0):

You support to modify at /appname/config.xml

When you add a platform, ionic will regenerate /appname/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml file for you to build android app. So, it will collect the permission from your plugin and config.xml to build AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: ionic also using cordova

Comment: You can edit both the files, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518006/how-to-edit-androidmanifest-xml-in-phonegap-3

Comment: @beaver, that answer is wrong. You can edit the AndroidManifest.xml, but you shouldn't, there are a lot of cases that can overwrite all the changes you did there

Comment: Yes, but it works in many cases.I do that in several projects without any problem